# Jenkins: take a post build action after many failures

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to configure Jenkins to do an action after 3 failed failures. What I can see that actions can be taken after only 1 failed build.

Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[Naginator Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Naginator+Plugin)**, you can choose how many times to retry running the job before firing an action.

Comment: Thank you! this answered my question.